# Add a shortcut to my tags in search

Tags: feature-request, search

A simple and powerful feature request:
a shortcut to my tags in search.
That is, if I write `[my tags] test`, in search box, it will be replace with ALL my tags  `[java] [html5] [css] ... test`.
It will be more graceful if this search-and-replace is not done in search box (i.e. I always see `[my tags]`, after a search too).

Answer (score 1):

> ### Low-tech solution warning!

You could just as easily save a bookmark in your browser to the search results page.

This is one for posts with the [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tags:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery

---

Another thought is that the [interesting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tab *should* be full of posts containing your favorite tags...

Comment: Using AND to combine the tags is likely to return no results for someone with more than a handful of favourite tags. You'll need to `[or]` the tags.

Comment: IMHO it is a little a weak solution since I must use an external tool (browser, maybe with another sync tool between office and home, etc.) .
If I do everything with bookmark, why must fill a list of favorite tags? Right now this list is not too much useful. Don't you think?

Comment: Low tech is low tech. It's not the best solution but it might keep you going till someone pops round and writes you a user script :P

Comment: Well, I was going to write the userscript over coffee break but got held back by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151409/searching-by-multiple-tags-ored-and-keywords).