# Searching by multiple tags ("OR"ed) and keywords

Tags: support, search

Say I want to search for the term "yield" in posts that are tagged either [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) **or** [python](/questions/tagged/python), how should I formulate the search phrase?

Based on the following:

- ["[python] yield"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20yield) - returns posts tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) and contains "yield"
- ["[c#] [python] yield"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20%5Bc%23%5D%20yield)  - returns posts  tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) **and** [python](/questions/tagged/python) and contains "yield"
- ["[c#] [or] [python]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+c%23) - returns posts  tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [python](/questions/tagged/python)

one might assume that the search phrase ["[c#] [or] [python] yield"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20%5Bor%5D%20%5Bc%23%5D%20yield) should do the trick. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: p.s. I was considering how a userscript can be used to provide [this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151400/add-a-shortcut-to-my-tags-in-search) when I hit this roadblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the "or" without square brackets.

Search it with

```
[c#] or [python] yield
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. I believe that was not possible when the question was asked circa 2 years ago :)